# Require an unknown constant and continue

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create "autorequire" for a package, namely if Ruby encounters an unknown constant it tries to require it, and continues where it left off if the require succeeds. Now I have something like this:

```
def autoload(&block)
  yield
rescue NameError => e
  if e.message[/constant/]
    require e.name.to_s.downcase rescue LoadError raise
    retry
  end
  raise
end
```

So if I use this like

```
autoload {
   print "Hello, "
   x = ArrayFields.new
   x << "World!"
   puts x[0]
}
```

As expected, it will print `Hello, Hello, World!`. So it handles the requiring of the constant, but executes the entire given block from the beginning. So how do I skip to where the fail occurred? This is mostly for academic interest, so I'm also interested in any dangers in attempts like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to jump back to the point right before the exception from a rescue-clause. A more feasible approach to do what you want would be to override [`const_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_missing).

Comment: I modified the example given in that doc to preserve the original error (uninitialized constant). But why doesn't this work as a one liner: `require file rescue LoadError super.const_missing(name)`. It will only work written as `begin require file rescue LoadError super.const_missing(name) end` and it must contain newlines after begin end etc..

Comment: @Tatu: The syntax for inline rescue is `exp1 rescue exp2`. You can't specify an exception type using inline rescue.

Comment: That was a typo (although syntax is allowed), but that and your reminder made me figure out why it doesn't work. LoadError is not a StandardError, hence it's not catched by the typeless rescue. Good to remember this for the latter example as well, it's always an inline rescue if the rescue is not on it's own line regardless how you write it on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has autoload, which will exist in Ruby 2.0 at least.

Comment: Note though that ruby's autoload does something different than what the OP's code does (i.e. you have to "pre-register" files with ruby's autoload).